# I have a grid view of images.I am selecting one image from it and showing it in activity2.xml.Now I want to drag this image view .How to do this?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout

I have one grid.class from where I am selecting an image and showing it in activity_main.xml.
Whenever I chose an image its id will be "imageChosen".
I am able to drag any image taken from drawable folder but not this dynamically chosen image,with image id.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are saying but assuming you have a grid adapter with some images , so you select one and you want that image to be shown in main activity; all you need is this:

1) create an array with all the images refs :

```
public class Images{
    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

2) On your item click in grid view send the index to the displayActivity:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent mInDisplay= new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                mInDisplay.putExtra("Index", position);
                startActivity(mInDisplay);
            }
        });
```

3) And in the DisplayActivity display the img :

```
 //onCreate()
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
                int index=bundle.getInt("Index");      
                ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img);
                mImage.setImageResource(Images.mIds[index]);
```